# TSQL Case When Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

With the rest of the query held constant:

```
 CAST((CASE WHEN z5.OrderNumber IS NULL AND z6.OrderNumber IS NULL 
               THEN 0 ELSE 1 
       END) AS BIT) AS NoProof
```

This takes over 1 minute to execute.

Whereas

```
 CAST((CASE WHEN z5.OrderNumber IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS BIT) AS NoProof
```

takes only 3 seconds to execute.

How would I make it take less time to execute while still getting the same result as the top query? And why is this a thing?

Remember the rest of the query is constant and doesn't change the only thing that causes the delay is the `AND`.

Comment: Step 1 is always: check the query plans ("Query -> Include Actual Execution Plan" in SSMS)

Comment: How are the 2 tables joined in the query?

Comment: both tables come from LEFT JOINs

Comment: You could try: `CAST(CASE WHEN  z5.OrderNumber IS NULL then 0 ELSE 1 END +  CASE WHEN z6.OrderNumber IS NULL then 0 ELSE 1 end AS BIT)`

Comment: One involves `z6`, the other does not. If `z6` occurs nowhere else in the result and the resulting rowset does not change, the optimizer is free to remove all access to the table altogether. This is why "the rest of the query is constant" is rather meaningless: the query is optimized as a whole, not clause by clause.

Comment: and, in addition the possibility that z6 could b dropped from consideration,  this is why grabbing an execution plan is essential. Often queries are not executed the way we "expect".

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps